# AS#3 organize variables loaded from PhP

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I am having a problem of how to organize my variables in flash that are from a PHP script.Ideally i want them in an array type format so i can loop through them.Below is some code to go with.

```
    function completeHandler(evt:Event){ // after loading the php
    var symbolsArray:Array = new Array()                      
    symbolsArray.push(evt.target.data.symbol_1);// php variable named: symbol_1, symbol_2
    trace(evt.target.data); 
    }
```

The above is allworking, the PHP variables are listed as symbol_1, symbol_2 etc

Instead of pushing each variable separably into the array i want a loop, along the lines of:

```
    function completeHandler(evt:Event){ 
    var symbolsArray:Array = new Array() 
    var counter =1                     
    symbolsArray.push(evt.target.data.symbol_+counter); this is the issue
    trace(symbolsArray[0]); //returns NaN 
    }
```

Below is the php return vars to flash to give an idea:

```
      $returnVars['symbol_1'] = $virtualReel1[0];
      $returnVars['symbol_2'] = $virtualReel1[1];
      $returnVars['symbol_3'] = $virtualReel1[2];
      $returnVars['symbol_4'] = $virtualReel2[0];
      $returnVars['symbol_5'] = $virtualReel2[1];
      //etc
      $returnString = http_build_query($returnVars);
      echo $returnString;
```

Comment: Just as a side comment. I like better to use AMFPhp and ValueObjects. This way you can create your own models and pass the objects between php and flex with ease.

Comment: Interesting , but the php script i have is fully accessible from any device, more or less its a basic function just returning some calculations from php, instead of using flash to calculate

Comment: I agree with you, Just wanted to mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned data can be treated as an Object (containing Objects) so you can loop thru it like so:

```
function completeHandler(evt:Event)
{
    var symbolsArray:Array = new Array();
    for each (var obj:Object in evt.target.data)
    {
        symbolsArray.push(obj);
    }
}
```

If you know all items are oif same type, you can cast the object. eg: if all Numbers:

```
symbolsArray.push(Number(obj));
```

Or Strings:

```
symbolsArray.push(String(obj));
```

Comment: again mate , i didnt know this was available to use , the concept was always in my head but ....excellent iv found like 20 uses i n 5 days for this mad

Answer (score 2):

```
 symbolsArray.push(evt.target.data["symbol_"+counter]);
```

If you need to dynamically query properties of an object, you address it as an Array or a Dictionary, by a string key, which can be dynamically formed. Works on anything.